How to check status of a BigQuery Table
I have a Dataflow job that writes to a BigQuery table. Every Dataflow job will create a new table.
I realize the write operation to the BigQuery table is asynchronous, i.e. the write operation to the BigQuery table may last for several more minutes after the dataflow job finishes.
Now I want to be able to query the status of the newly created table and get its status like: "Being written to" and "Write completed". Is this something we can do through the GCP Java client library?
If not, I have an alternative idea. I know the number of rows that will be write to the table, during the dataflow execution. I can compare the number of rows in the table against this number and see if they match. If yes, the write operation is completed. However, I don't know where I can put the dynamically generated row count which is generated during dataflow execution.
Please help.

Maybe you could use the BigQuery JOBS view?
You would have to store the job_id of your query, then search for it inside the JOBS view with something like:
SELECT
*
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
  WHERE job_id = "JOB_ID"

After that, this will let you have information on the status of your query by using the job_stages.status STRUCT. When the query is done, it will be marked as COMPLETED.
You can also access this type of information inside Cloud Logging
